# Lokijs, module.exports existing collections

Tags: node.js, lokijs

is it possible to load existing database(maybe synchronously) and export collection from it?

i.e.

*lokijs_data.js*

```
var loki = require('lokijs');
var testDb = new loki('test-db.json', { autosave: true, autoload: true });

if(!testDb.getCollection('coll1')) {
    testDb.addCollection('coll1')
}   

module.exports = {
    coll1: testDb.getCollection('coll1')
}
```

*app.js*

```
var coll1 = require('./lokijs_data').coll1;
console.log(coll1); //prints 'null'
```

Thank You!

Comment: it should be perfectly feasible. Have you tried? I can't see a reason why it wouldn't work.

Comment: it seems like collection checks(get/add) should be placed in autoloadCallback, otherwise collection gets always recreated. But if the check is placed in callback, how to exports collections ?

Comment: have you tried to put the module.exports statement in the autoloadCallback?

Comment: thx for reply. it is not possible to put module.exports in callback, edited question a bit. what I want to do is to load test-db.json synchronously, then add collections if they do not exist and export them. if this code if(!testDb.getCollection('coll1')) {
    testDb.addCollection('coll1')
}  is used outside autoloadCallback testDb.getCollection('coll1') will always return null and testDb.addCollection('coll1') will recreate collection, erasing all existing data. But if I place this code in autoloadCallback the code in module.exports coll1: testDb.getCollection('coll1') will return null

Comment: yeah the problem is that i should really change autoloadCallback to be a promise, I'll have a think about this, head over to github and open an issue maybe, so i can fix up a permanent solution

Comment: or maybe add possibility to load databases synchronously :)